# Wordpress: How to fix if a newly added page menu item turns into an empty individual link?

Tags: wordpress, menu, megamenu, divi

I got a client with a wordpress website. It has a Divi theme and a Uber Menu (Mega Menu?).
Their issue is, when adding a page to the existing and working menu, it is shown, but then after publishing, the added item became an empty individual link.

I tried A LOT. I increased the max_item_value to 10000, and increased other values, too. I looked inside the wp_debug log, and tried to fix some issues there, but it didn't really help. Wordpress and all plugins are up-to-date. And I also deactivated all Plugins and switched to the TwentyTwo-or-something-Theme, and the problem still occurs. And now I'm out of ideas.

What could cause this error?

Here you can have my wp_debug log - maybe you can get something out of it...

```
    [23-Jun-2023 14:43:00 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: Unable to release actions from claim id 0. in /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-content/plugins/action-scheduler/classes/data-stores/ActionScheduler_DBStore.php:1030
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-content/plugins/action-scheduler/classes/ActionScheduler_QueueRunner.php(173): ActionScheduler_DBStore->release_claim()
#1 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-content/plugins/action-scheduler/classes/ActionScheduler_QueueRunner.php(136): ActionScheduler_QueueRunner->do_batch()
#2 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): ActionScheduler_QueueRunner->run()
#3 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#4 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-includes/plugin.php(565): WP_Hook->do_action()
#5 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-cron.php(188): do_action_ref_array()
#6 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-content/plugins/action-scheduler/classes/data-stores/ActionScheduler_DBStore.php on line 1030    
[23-Jun-2023 14:43:00 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: Unable to release actions from claim id 0. in /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-content/plugins/action-scheduler/classes/data-stores/ActionScheduler_DBStore.php:1030
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-content/plugins/action-scheduler/classes/ActionScheduler_FatalErrorMonitor.php(52): ActionScheduler_DBStore->release_claim()
#1 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): ActionScheduler_FatalErrorMonitor->handle_unexpected_shutdown()
#2 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#3 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action()
#4 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-includes/load.php(1144): do_action()
#5 [internal function]: shutdown_action_hook()
#6 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-content/plugins/action-scheduler/classes/data-stores/ActionScheduler_DBStore.php on line 1030    
[23-Jun-2023 14:43:26 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: Unable to release actions from claim id 0. in /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-content/plugins/action-scheduler/classes/data-stores/ActionScheduler_DBStore.php:1030
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-content/plugins/action-scheduler/classes/ActionScheduler_QueueRunner.php(173): ActionScheduler_DBStore->release_claim()
#1 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-content/plugins/action-scheduler/classes/ActionScheduler_QueueRunner.php(136): ActionScheduler_QueueRunner->do_batch()
#2 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): ActionScheduler_QueueRunner->run()
#3 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#4 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action()
#5 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-content/plugins/action-scheduler/classes/ActionScheduler_AsyncRequest_QueueRunner.php(52): do_action()
#6 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-content/plugins/action-scheduler/lib/WP_Async_Request.php(177): ActionScheduler_AsyncRequest_QueueRunner->handle()
#7 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): WP_Async_Request->maybe_handle()
#8 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#9 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action()
#10 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php(188): do_action()
#11 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-content/plugins/action-scheduler/classes/data-stores/ActionScheduler_DBStore.php on line 1030    
[23-Jun-2023 14:43:26 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: Unable to release actions from claim id 0. in /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-content/plugins/action-scheduler/classes/data-stores/ActionScheduler_DBStore.php:1030
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-content/plugins/action-scheduler/classes/ActionScheduler_FatalErrorMonitor.php(52): ActionScheduler_DBStore->release_claim()
#1 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): ActionScheduler_FatalErrorMonitor->handle_unexpected_shutdown()
#2 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#3 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action()
#4 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-includes/load.php(1144): do_action()
#5 [internal function]: shutdown_action_hook()
#6 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-content/plugins/action-scheduler/classes/data-stores/ActionScheduler_DBStore.php on line 1030    
[23-Jun-2023 14:43:32 UTC]  .../AnimatedLinks/AnimatedLinks.php:37  DIVIENHANCER_AnimatedLinks::get_advanced_fields_config():
You're Doing It Wrong! DIVIENHANCER_AnimatedLinks::$advanced_tab_options doesn't exist.

[23-Jun-2023 14:43:32 UTC]  .../bingMapChild/bingMapChild.php:80  DIVIENHANCER_bingMapChild::get_advanced_fields_config():
You're Doing It Wrong! DIVIENHANCER_bingMapChild::$advanced_tab_options doesn't exist.

[23-Jun-2023 14:43:32 UTC]  .../builder/class-et-builder-element.php:851  ET_Builder_Element::__construct():
You're Doing It Wrong! Module setting definition for icon has a deprecated value: 'et_pb_get_font_icon_list' for parameter 'renderer'. Use 'select_icon' instead.

[23-Jun-2023 14:43:32 UTC]  .../builder/class-et-builder-element.php:851  ET_Builder_Element::__construct():
You're Doing It Wrong! You're using wrong type for the 'main_color'. It should be 'color-alpha' instead of 'color'.

[23-Jun-2023 14:43:32 UTC]  .../carouselChild/carouselChild.php:85  DIVIENHANCER_carouselChild::get_advanced_fields_config():
You're Doing It Wrong! DIVIENHANCER_carouselChild::$advanced_tab_options doesn't exist.

[23-Jun-2023 14:43:32 UTC]  .../flipBoxChild/flipBoxChild.php:37  DIVIENHANCER_flipboxchild::get_advanced_fields_config():
You're Doing It Wrong! DIVIENHANCER_flipboxchild::$advanced_tab_options doesn't exist.

[23-Jun-2023 14:43:32 UTC]  .../builder/class-et-builder-element.php:851  ET_Builder_Element::__construct():
You're Doing It Wrong! Module setting definition for icontitle has a deprecated value: 'et_pb_get_font_icon_list' for parameter 'renderer'. Use 'select_icon' instead.

[23-Jun-2023 14:43:32 UTC]  .../tagCloudChild/tagCloudChild.php:154  DIVIENHANCER_tagCloudChild::get_advanced_fields_config():
You're Doing It Wrong! DIVIENHANCER_tagCloudChild::$advanced_tab_options doesn't exist.

[23-Jun-2023 14:43:32 UTC]  .../timeLineChild/timeLineChild.php:126  DIVIENHANCER_timelineChild::get_advanced_fields_config():
You're Doing It Wrong! DIVIENHANCER_timelineChild::$advanced_tab_options doesn't exist.

[23-Jun-2023 14:43:33 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Class property PLL_Language::$search_url is deprecated, use PLL_Language::get_search_url() instead.
Error handler in /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-content/plugins/polylang/include/language-deprecated.php on line 253    
[23-Jun-2023 14:43:33 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Class property PLL_Language::$search_url is deprecated, use PLL_Language::get_search_url() instead.
Error handler in /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-content/plugins/polylang/include/language-deprecated.php on line 253    
[23-Jun-2023 14:43:33 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Class property PLL_Language::$search_url is deprecated, use PLL_Language::get_search_url() instead.
Error handler in /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-content/plugins/polylang/include/language-deprecated.php on line 253    
[23-Jun-2023 14:43:33 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Class property PLL_Language::$search_url is deprecated, use PLL_Language::get_search_url() instead.
Error handler in /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-content/plugins/polylang/include/language-deprecated.php on line 253    
[23-Jun-2023 14:43:33 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Class property PLL_Language::$search_url is deprecated, use PLL_Language::get_search_url() instead.
Error handler in /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-content/plugins/polylang/include/language-deprecated.php on line 253    
[23-Jun-2023 14:43:34 UTC]  .../AnimatedLinks/AnimatedLinks.php:37  DIVIENHANCER_AnimatedLinks::get_advanced_fields_config():
You're Doing It Wrong! DIVIENHANCER_AnimatedLinks::$advanced_tab_options doesn't exist.

[23-Jun-2023 14:43:34 UTC]  .../bingMapChild/bingMapChild.php:80  DIVIENHANCER_bingMapChild::get_advanced_fields_config():
You're Doing It Wrong! DIVIENHANCER_bingMapChild::$advanced_tab_options doesn't exist.

[23-Jun-2023 14:43:34 UTC]  .../builder/class-et-builder-element.php:851  ET_Builder_Element::__construct():
You're Doing It Wrong! Module setting definition for icon has a deprecated value: 'et_pb_get_font_icon_list' for parameter 'renderer'. Use 'select_icon' instead.

[23-Jun-2023 14:43:34 UTC]  .../builder/class-et-builder-element.php:851  ET_Builder_Element::__construct():
You're Doing It Wrong! You're using wrong type for the 'main_color'. It should be 'color-alpha' instead of 'color'.

[23-Jun-2023 14:43:34 UTC]  .../carouselChild/carouselChild.php:85  DIVIENHANCER_carouselChild::get_advanced_fields_config():
You're Doing It Wrong! DIVIENHANCER_carouselChild::$advanced_tab_options doesn't exist.

[23-Jun-2023 14:43:34 UTC]  .../flipBoxChild/flipBoxChild.php:37  DIVIENHANCER_flipboxchild::get_advanced_fields_config():
You're Doing It Wrong! DIVIENHANCER_flipboxchild::$advanced_tab_options doesn't exist.

[23-Jun-2023 14:43:34 UTC]  .../builder/class-et-builder-element.php:851  ET_Builder_Element::__construct():
You're Doing It Wrong! Module setting definition for icontitle has a deprecated value: 'et_pb_get_font_icon_list' for parameter 'renderer'. Use 'select_icon' instead.

[23-Jun-2023 14:43:34 UTC]  .../tagCloudChild/tagCloudChild.php:154  DIVIENHANCER_tagCloudChild::get_advanced_fields_config():
You're Doing It Wrong! DIVIENHANCER_tagCloudChild::$advanced_tab_options doesn't exist.

[23-Jun-2023 14:43:34 UTC]  .../timeLineChild/timeLineChild.php:126  DIVIENHANCER_timelineChild::get_advanced_fields_config():
You're Doing It Wrong! DIVIENHANCER_timelineChild::$advanced_tab_options doesn't exist.
```

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's an issue with the **Action Scheduler plugin** based on the provided wp_debug log. The error message indicates that there's a problem releasing actions from claim ID 0. This particular error can lead to unexpected behavior on your WordPress site.

Comment: I already checked the action scheduler but it didn't help... Now I tried to find out with the health check plugin what plugin causes this problem, but it even doesn't work without any plugin active. 

Comment: actually, there are two plugins I see that are interfering: one of them is the Action Scheduler plugin and the other one is the Polylang plugin.  i saw errors in this line : `File: /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-content/plugins/action-scheduler/classes/data-stores/ActionScheduler_DBStore.php
Line: 1030`
and for other plugin in this line : File: `/var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/httpdocs/xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/wp-content/plugins/polylang/include/language-deprecated.php
Line: 253`

Comment: Like I said before - even with no plugin active, it doesn't work 

Comment: oh sorry, I misunderstood. maybe it is the database issue: There may be inconsistencies or corruption in the WordPress database.  using a plugin like "WP-DBManager" or "WP Optimize" to repair and optimize the database may help you. dont forget to Take a backup of your database before performing any modifications.

Comment: I'm copying the project now to somewhere else, so I can test some things like downgrade wordpress. I will give you the bounty, because you actually tried. So thank you!

Comment: thanks, if you found any solutions ill be happy to hear it